# Shunt: calculate dissipation resistor

Tags: sensor, shunt

How can I calculate `Rdis` in [this](http://ubuntuone.com/32MHYUClRjJIm1PRQW2miN) circuit.

[image]

The load connected to `Vset` in [this](http://www.e2v.com/e2v/assets/File/sensors_datasheets/electrochem/ec4-250-no.pdf) sensor for -300mV biasing.

[Here](http://ubuntuone.com/7hQjxMYNbCnxbuBoEMwPkp) the complete circuit. The sensor need a -300mV bias voltage between sensing and reference pins.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify it more please?

The 300 mV is the bias for the sensor according to the datasheet. In your question appear as negative. Is it due to the way the sensor is connected?

Where is the sensor connected?

Is the resistance marked as "300" a model for the sensor?

Comment: I'm adding the entire circuit in next minutes for clarify my question. Thanks.

Comment: By inspection if the mid point is 2.5V then Rdis (5V - 2.5V) must equal 2k2 + 300R (2.5V - 0V) = 2k5

Comment: I don't understand your new circuit. The amps seem to be in a positive feedback configuration, which makes them unstable.

You must redesign your circuit. I recommend design the bias for the sensor an then, the signal conditioning part. You must take into account that the ouput of your sensor is current. Check out the concept of transimpedance amplifiers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current-to-voltage_converter

Comment: @jsrmalvarez You are right the two OpAmp input are inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am glad you linked directly to the
[EC4-250-NO Nitric Oxide Electrochemical Sensor datasheet](http://www.e2v.com/e2v/assets/File/sensors_datasheets/electrochem/ec4-250-no.pdf).

That datasheet specified an applied potential of +300 mV
and mentions "Operating circuit ... see Electrochemical Toxic Sensor Application Note".
I'm assuming that's alluding to the
["ev2: Electrochemical Sensors Application Note 2: Design of Electronics for Electrochemical Gas Sensors"](http://www.sgxsensortech.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/AN2-Design-of-Electronics-for-Electrochemical-Sensors.pdf).
(And *not* alluding to the similar-sounding 
["e2v: Electrochemical Sensors Application Note 2: Support Electronics for Toxic Electrochemical Sensors"](http://www.cdiweb.com/datasheets/e2v/a1a-ec_sensors_an2_1_v1.pdf) which assumes zero bias voltage, and so won't work with this sensor, since this sensor requires a 300 mV bias voltage).
That app note specifically points out (in Table 1) that the EC4-250-NO
is designed to have the Vsense electrode +300 mV positive relative to the Vref electrode.

You are trying to build something functionally equivalent to
"Figure 4 –Biased Sensor Circuit with Single Power Rail"
from that datasheet, right?

The LM285 datasheet guarantees that, if some current Ir in a given range is forced through the LM285, the voltage is a high-precision approximation to 2.5 V.
According to page 3 of the the datasheet,
that range is Imin == 12 uA <= Ir <= 1 mA for 1 mV precision,
up to 20 mA for 20 mV precision.

You need to pick Rdis to set Ir in that given range.
So we have

```
Vcc == 5.0 V ---Rdis--+-- Ir through shunt diode ---GND
                      |
                      +-- 2.5 V reference voltage (set by shunt diode)
                      |
                      +-- 2k2 Ohm + 300R Ohm ------GND
```

ignoring the insignificant bias leakage in the op amps and insignificant leakage in the capacitors.

So we use Ohm's law to calculate 1 mA through the resistors to GND,
plus 12 uA <= Ir <= 1 mA through the shunt resistor,
to give the total current going through Rdis

Since we know Rdis has about 2.5 V across it, when the circuit is operating correctly,
Then we use Ohm's law to calculate Rdis.
I get

**1.25 kOhm <= Rdis <= 2.47 kOhm.**

p.s.:
Clear, easy-to-understand schematics are surprisingly difficult to draw,
and yet they make it *much* easier for people to help you.

In the future, you might consider:

When I use a voltage reference diode on my schematics,
I prefer to use a symbol that looks more like
Figure 2 in the [LM285 2.5V reference diode datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/282/lm185-2.5-n-179966.pdf)
rather than a mysterious empty box.

Also, when I break up a schematic across multiple sheets,
rather than "2.5 V" on one and "Virtual_GND" on the other,
I prefer to give a net the same name on every sheet it is used.

p. p.s.:

Is there some reason you want to design and build from scratch your own circuit, rather than using
an off-the-shelf, ready-to-go PCB
already designed and built for that specific sensor?

Such as, for example,

- [Gas Sensor Evaluation Kit from e2v](http://www.e2v.com/e2v/assets/File/sensors_datasheets/Electrochem/ECVQ-EK3.pdf) (and its [user guide](http://www.mymectronic.com/datasheet/13059_4173113_ECVQ-EK3userGuide.pdf) )
- [SensorBox, the EveryAware mobile platform](http://www.everyaware.eu/resources/deliverables/D1_1.pdf)
- [CN0234: Single Supply, Micropower Toxic Gas Detector Using an Electrochemical Sensor](http://www.analog.com/en/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0234/vc.html)
- [Electrochemical Gas Sensor Transmitters](http://www.membrapor.ch/products.htm)

Comment: Thank you @davidcary for your precious advice. The first p.s. is a good observation but my problem is that i need to associate in KiCAD this component to an 8-pin footprint. How can I "fix" this projecting problem?

Comment: For the p.p.s. the reason is that my workgroup are trying to realize a wireless sensor network for environmental monitoring. We want to compare different sensors for the same gas and obtain finally a good gas sensor node for our network.

Comment: I've just read the four link you posted on your p.p.s. The second might be very useful for our work since we are a research foundation and we are working on an open hardware project. With respect to other links, they refer to ready-to-use board but they costs are excessive in relation to those of the realization of a custom board.